# Apache won't start

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, centos

My webserver was working earlier, but after moving `.conf` files from a vps into the main server, I can't get apache to start.

Here is what the cmli says:

```
[orca@orcacomputers conf.d]$ sudo systemctl status httpd.service
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-11-26 21:43:34 PST; 24min ago
Docs: man:httpd(8)
       man:apachectl(8)
Process: 28240 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 28235 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 28235 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 26 21:43:33 orcacomputers.orcainbox systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Nov 26 21:43:34 orcacomputers.orcainbox systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 26 21:43:34 orcacomputers.orcainbox kill[28240]: kill: cannot find process ""
Nov 26 21:43:34 orcacomputers.orcainbox systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 26 21:43:34 orcacomputers.orcainbox systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Nov 26 21:43:34 orcacomputers.orcainbox systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Nov 26 21:43:34 orcacomputers.orcainbox systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
[orca@orcacomputers conf.d]$ apachectl configtest
Syntax OK
```

Here is the output of journalctl -xe -u httpd

```
[orca@orcacomputers conf.d $ journalctl -xe -u httpd
Nov 26 20:31:56 orcacomputers.orcainbox systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 26 20:31:56 orcacomputers.orcainbox kill[19255]: kill: cannot find process ""
Nov 26 20:31:56 orcacomputers.orcainbox systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 26 20:31:56 orcacomputers.orcainbox systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit httpd.service has failed.]
```

Output of `cat /etc/httpd/logs/ssl_error_log`:

```
[orca@orcacomputers conf.d]$ sudo cat /etc/httpd/logs/ssl_error_log
[sudo] password for orca: 
[Sun Nov 24 12:15:39.697424 2019] [proxy_http:error] [pid 12542] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 45.9.148.123:59108] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 174.1.56.6:80
[Sun Nov 24 12:15:39.697501 2019] [proxy:error] [pid 12542] [client 45.9.148.123:59108] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /
[Sun Nov 24 12:58:28.404286 2019] [proxy_http:error] [pid 17724] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 174.1.56.6:42924] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 174.1.56.6:80
[Sun Nov 24 12:58:28.404333 2019] [proxy:error] [pid 17724] [client 174.1.56.6:42924] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /xry/user_management.php
[Sun Nov 24 13:55:24.971688 2019] [ssl:error] [pid 24203] [client 167.99.143.120:48898] AH02042: rejecting client initiated renegotiation
[Sun Nov 24 19:14:41.420892 2019] [proxy_http:error] [pid 1839] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 184.105.247.196:58852] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 174.1.56.6:80
[Sun Nov 24 19:14:41.420935 2019] [proxy:error] [pid 1839] [client 184.105.247.196:58852] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /
[Mon Nov 25 00:23:59.413321 2019] [proxy_http:error] [pid 9041] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 198.108.66.112:20702] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 174.1.56.6:80
[Mon Nov 25 00:23:59.413368 2019] [proxy:error] [pid 9041] [client 198.108.66.112:20702] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /
[Mon Nov 25 07:11:03.875248 2019] [proxy_http:error] [pid 30401] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 71.6.232.7:53834] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 174.1.56.6:80
[Mon Nov 25 07:11:03.875285 2019] [proxy:error] [pid 30401] [client 71.6.232.7:53834] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /
[Mon Nov 25 08:03:11.651298 2019] [proxy_http:error] [pid 30507] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 173.16.134.5:44008] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 174.1.56.6:80
[Mon Nov 25 08:03:11.651339 2019] [proxy:error] [pid 30507] [client 173.16.134.5:44008] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /xry/user_management.php
[Mon Nov 25 14:48:01.714166 2019] [:error] [pid 7936] [client 173.16.134.5:50038] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Smarty' not found in /usr/lib/php4/libs/Smarty_Compiler.class.php on line 35, referer: http://192.168.1.10/sugarcrm/index.php?action=ajaxui
[Mon Nov 25 14:48:04.573289 2019] [:error] [pid 7937] [client 173.16.134.5:50040] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Smarty' not found in /usr/lib/php4/libs/Smarty_Compiler.class.php on line 35, referer: http://192.168.1.10/sugarcrm/index.php?action=ajaxui
[Mon Nov 25 14:48:06.215679 2019] [:error] [pid 7938] [client 173.16.134.5:50042] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Smarty' not found in /usr/lib/php4/libs/Smarty_Compiler.class.php on line 35, referer: http://192.168.1.10/sugarcrm/index.php?action=ajaxui
[Tue Nov 26 20:28:57.411934 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 18766] AH01898: Unable to configure permitted SSL ciphers
[Tue Nov 26 20:28:57.412118 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 18766] SSL Library Error: error:1410D0B9:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list:no cipher match
[Tue Nov 26 20:31:56.190027 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 19249] AH01898: Unable to configure permitted SSL ciphers
[Tue Nov 26 20:31:56.190060 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 19249] SSL Library Error: error:1410D0B9:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list:no cipher match
[Tue Nov 26 21:12:32.416614 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 24344] AH01898: Unable to configure permitted SSL ciphers
[Tue Nov 26 21:12:32.416659 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 24344] SSL Library Error: error:1410D0B9:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list:no cipher match
[Tue Nov 26 21:24:19.396550 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 25637] AH01898: Unable to configure permitted SSL ciphers
[Tue Nov 26 21:24:19.396588 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 25637] SSL Library Error: error:1410D0B9:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list:no cipher match
[Tue Nov 26 21:29:29.391832 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 26454] AH01898: Unable to configure permitted SSL ciphers
[Tue Nov 26 21:29:29.391888 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 26454] SSL Library Error: error:1410D0B9:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list:no cipher match
[Tue Nov 26 21:31:40.132210 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 26901] AH01898: Unable to configure permitted SSL ciphers
[Tue Nov 26 21:31:40.132251 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 26901] SSL Library Error: error:1410D0B9:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list:no cipher match
[Tue Nov 26 21:32:26.114430 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 26987] AH01898: Unable to configure permitted SSL ciphers
[Tue Nov 26 21:32:26.114477 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 26987] SSL Library Error: error:1410D0B9:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list:no cipher match
[Tue Nov 26 21:32:56.558897 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 27051] AH01898: Unable to configure permitted SSL ciphers
[Tue Nov 26 21:32:56.558936 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 27051] SSL Library Error: error:1410D0B9:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list:no cipher match
[Tue Nov 26 21:43:34.017631 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 28235] AH01898: Unable to configure permitted SSL ciphers
[Tue Nov 26 21:43:34.017677 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 28235] SSL Library Error: error:1410D0B9:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list:no cipher match
[Tue Nov 26 21:53:34.989323 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 29398] AH01898: Unable to configure permitted SSL ciphers
[Tue Nov 26 21:53:34.989377 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 29398] SSL Library Error: error:1410D0B9:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list:no cipher match
[Tue Nov 26 21:54:08.487528 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 29446] AH01898: Unable to configure permitted SSL ciphers
[Tue Nov 26 21:54:08.487575 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 29446] SSL Library Error: error:1410D0B9:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list:no cipher match
[Tue Nov 26 21:56:21.931523 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 29841] AH01898: Unable to configure permitted SSL ciphers
[Tue Nov 26 21:56:21.931555 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 29841] SSL Library Error: error:1410D0B9:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list:no cipher match
```

Comment: And what does your Apache error.log say?

Comment: Apache Error Log https://paste.linux.community/view/dd546551

The log is saying  public_html does not exist for a bunch of domains but the directory public_html is there for each domain.

Comment: The messages at the top aren't very important (they're also from two days ago). Your latest start attempts are at the bottom, where it says "Fatal error initialising mod_ssl". See that other ssl_error_log file it's pointing to.

Comment: Use `journalctl -xe -u httpd` for the latest entries. Preferably add them to your question, so we can maintain proper documentation on this site. Your pastebin quite blatantly tells you about a problem with `ssl` and to check `/etc/httpd/logs/ssl_error_log`. Please add that, too.

Comment: added the outputs, looks really messy which is why i used paste bin

Comment: Best bet at this point is to uninstall httpd and reinstall it then move one .conf file over at a time.  

This article was great to uninstall httpd (Centos7)
https://www.linuxhelp.com/questions/how-to-completely-remove-apache-package-on-centos-7-6

I reinstalled and it works now! Problem solved.